# char[] to full quantified name of java class for method parameter

Tags: java, reflection, apache-commons-lang3

Problem with reflectiion in java

SampleClass

```
Class Question{
        public  int a   ( String a, char[] c,int b) { return  b; }    
}
```

Method to get method with name and parameters via reflection

```
 public Method getMethodWithParams(Class<?> klasa, String methodName, Class<?>[] params) throws
            SecurityException, NoSuchMethodException {
       Class<?>[] primitivesToWrappers =
                  ClassUtils.primitivesToWrappers(params);
        Method publicMethod = MethodUtils.getMatchingAccessibleMethod(klasa,
                                                                      methodName,
                                                                      primitivesToWrappers );
        System.out.println(publicMethod.toGenericString());

        return publicMethod;
    }

 private void printParams(Type[] types) throws ClassNotFoundException {

        for (Type genericParameterType : types) {
            System.out.println(genericParameterType.toString());

        }

    }
```

Main Program

```
Question cls = new Question();
    Class<?>[] paramString = new Class<?>[3];
            paramString[0] = String.class;
            paramString[1] = char[].class;
            paramString[2] = int.class;
     Method methodParams1 = getMethodParams(cls.getClass(),"a", paramString);
            System.out.println(methodParams1.getName());
            Type[] genericTypes = methodParams1.getParameterTypes();
            printParams(genericTypes);
```

output is:

> a
>
> class java.lang.String
>
> class [C
>
> int

Problem is that next test fails

```
Character testCharacterObjArray = new Character[]
Class<?> aClass = ClassUtils.getClass("[C", true);
Assert.assertEquals(testCharacterObjArray.getClass(), aClass);
```

ClassUtils is from org.apache.commons.lang3

Looking for a library to get "[Ljava.lang.Character;" instead of "[C", since it appears ClassUtils.primitivesToWrappers() fails.

Solution based on [stephen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/139985/stephen-c):

```
public Class<?> convertStringToClass(String str) throws
        ClassNotFoundException {
    Class<?> aClass = ClassUtils.getClass(str, true);

    if (aClass.isArray()) {

        Class<?> primitiveToWrapper =
                 ClassUtils.primitiveToWrapper(aClass.getComponentType());
        Object newInstance = Array.newInstance(primitiveToWrapper, 0);
        System.out.println("****" + newInstance.getClass().getName());
        return ClassUtils.
                getClass(newInstance.getClass().getName(), true);
    }
    else {
        return ClassUtils.primitiveToWrapper(aClass);
    }

}
```

Comment: I do not understand the test, why you do not want to have testCharacterObjArray = char[].class ? (btw, the test cannot be compiled)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that this fails:

```
Character[] testCharacterObjArray = new Character[]
Class<?> aClass = ClassUtils.getClass("[C", true);
Assert.assertSame(testCharacterObjArray.getClass(), aClass);
```

is that "[C" denotes a `char[]` not a `Character[]`.

The reason that you can't call `ClassUtils.primitivesToWrappers()` on `char[].class` is that that `char[]` is not a primitive type!

If you want to map an array-of-primitive class to an array-of-wrapper class, then:

1. Use `Class.isArray()` to test if the type is an array
2. Use `Class.getComponentType()` to get the base type
3. If the base type is primitive, map it.
4. Create the array type of the mapped base type by using `Arrays.newInstance(baseType, ...)` to create an array and then call `getClass()` on it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that your problem is not only in `primitivesToWrappers`.

Also `getMatchingAccessibleMethod` doesn't as I would expect:

In Java I can call:

```
    new Question().foo("a", new char[] {'a'}, 1);
    new Question().foo("b", new char[] {'b'}, Integer.valueOf(2));

    new Question().bar("c", new char[] {'c'}, 3);
    new Question().bar("d", new char[] {'d'}, Integer.valueOf(4));
```

this results in compilation error in Java:

```
    new Question().foo("b", new char[] {'b'}, Integer.valueOf(2));
```

but in MethodUtils tests:

```
    Method m1 = MethodUtils.getMatchingAccessibleMethod(Question.class, "foo", String.class, char[].class, int.class);
    System.out.println("m1:" + m1);
    Method m2 = MethodUtils.getMatchingAccessibleMethod(Question.class, "foo", String.class, char[].class, Integer.class);
    System.out.println("m2: " + m2);
    Method m3 = MethodUtils.getMatchingAccessibleMethod(Question.class, "foo", String.class, Character[].class, Integer.class);
    System.out.println("m3: " + m3);

    Method mb1 = MethodUtils.getMatchingAccessibleMethod(Question.class, "bar", String.class, char[].class, int.class);
    System.out.println("mb1: " +mb1);
    Method mb2 = MethodUtils.getMatchingAccessibleMethod(Question.class, "bar", String.class, char[].class, Integer.class);
    System.out.println("mb2:" + mb2);
```

the output is (and I'd expect not null for m2 and mb1):

```
m1: public int LangTest$Question.foo(java.lang.String,char[],int)
m2: null
m3: null
mb1: null
mb2: public int LangTest$Question.bar(java.lang.String,char[],java.lang.Integer)
```

I modified your Question class to:

```
static class Question {
    public  int foo( String a, char[] c,int b) { return  b; }
    public  int bar( String a, char[] c,Integer b) { return  b; }
}
```

Comment: That's something to consider too